# How to add isometric (rts-alike) perspective and scolling in unity?

Tags: unity, camera, rts, simulations

I want to develop some RTS/simulation game. Therefore I need a camera perspective like one knows it from Anno 1602 - 1404, as well as the camera scrolling.
I think this is called isometric perspective (and scrolling).

[image: It should look like this] [image: or that]

But I honestly have no clue how to manage this. I tried some things I found on google, but they were not satisfying.

Can you give me some good tutorials or advice for managing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: isometric usually means "orthographic" you could try looking up Unity info on orthographic cameras

Comment: Also - Unity3d has it own site as well you can probably get much better unity specific answers there... http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure those screenshots are using ortho projection though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't always play RTSs, but, when I do, I fail miserably.  As such, I can offer general implementation ideas based on my understanding of RTS camera movement/mechanics.

The isometric perspective could be fairly easily achieved by setting your camera to [orthographic](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographic.html) and finding a rotation that looks down at an angle that "feels right" for your game.

Scrolling around the world in this style is just movement on the world's XZ plane; you would not change its height at all.

Answer (score 1):

Orthographic projection can be done in advance, making it simply a 2d game with a tileset constructed either: from a 3d model with orthographic projection on (in blender you can set this in the camera's object data properties window), or by manually drawing the pixels.

This way you bypass the need for projecting at runtime, which will make the game significantly faster to run.